# Can protein sample be made 2% Triton X-100 free?

Tags: proteins, purification

The protein I am purifying needed an elution buffer with 2% Triton X-100. I formulated the elution buffer not keeping the CMC in mind. My goal is to make my protein sample triton free to check its stability and quantify its concentration. Lately, I learnt that micelles can be broken down upon dilution. So, I've diluted my protein sample below triton's CMC and tried concentrating it using Sartorius Vivaspin 5K (PES resin). I loaded 500 ul of diluted sample and was left with 100 ul after concentration using vivaspin. But, this sample gave an abnormal reading of above 3 OD after blanking against the buffer it is in. I presume, triton's interference is causing these discrepant readings.

Comment: You'll probably have to do multiple buffer exchanges if using a centrifugal filter. Dialysis is another option.

Comment: This is a dialysed protein sample against Tris-HCl. Multiple buffer exchanges meaning, re-adding fresh buffer to the remain on filter?

Comment: If dialysis didn't remove it, I doubt filtration would. You can get beads specifically designed to remove Triton X-100 by adsorption.